# how to select clicked element in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs in this i have defined components and i am passing title to audio cards and by using title i am also defining source of the audio files. and after clicking on that particular component i want to play that particular audio file.
in js we can achieve this using $(this).find();

but in reactjs how to do it can anyone help me

```
import React from 'react';
import AudioCard from './AudioCard';
import '../css/RecommendedAudios.css';

function RecommandedAudios() {
    return (
        <div className="recommandedaudios">
            <h2>Recommanded</h2>
            <div className="recommandedaudios_audios">
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Alive" />
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Dust & Gold" />
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Stars" />
                <AudioCard title="Arrows to Athens - Used to be" />
                <AudioCard title="Bryan Adams - Here I am" />
                <AudioCard title="My Heart Belongs to You" />
                <AudioCard title="Ravenscode - My Escape" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecommandedAudios;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/AudioCard.css';
import PlayArrowIcon from '@material-ui/icons/PlayArrow';
function AudioCard({ title, timestamp }) {
    var playsong = () => {
        const select = document.querySelector("audio");
        select.play();
        
    };
    return (
        <div onClick={playsong} className="audiocard">
            <PlayArrowIcon />
            <div className="audiocard_info">
                <div className="audiocard_title">
                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                    <audio src={require(`../sounds/${title}.mp3`)}></audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AudioCard;
```

Comment: document.querySelector("audio") will return the first "audio" tag in the HTML, not the specific one you're looking for, I suggest to add id from outside

Comment: yes i know in js i would have used $(this).querySelector("audio); but it doesn't work in react js is there an alternative for the same in reactjs

Comment: yes you can use ref, https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: playsong function Call like `onClick={ ()=> playsong()}`

Comment: @NitishKurhadkar added answer using ref, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelector("audio") will return the first "audio" tag in the HTML, not the specific one you're looking for

you can use ref:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

function AudioCard({ title, timestamp }) {

const audioEl = useRef(null);

const playsong = () => audioEl.current.play();

    return (
        <div onClick={playsong} className="audiocard">
            <PlayArrowIcon />
            <div className="audiocard_info">
                <div className="audiocard_title">
                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                    <audio ref={audioEl} src={require(`../sounds/${title}.mp3`)}></audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-audio-player` instead of using `query selector` and HTML audio tag
you can install it by

```
npm install --save react-audio-player
```

and inport the library to your code and use

```
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
const [audio,ReferAudio] = useState()
 ...........

<div onClick={playsong} className="audiocard">
            <PlayArrowIcon />
            <div className="audiocard_info">
                <div className="audiocard_title">
                    <h5>{title}</h5>
                  <ReactAudioPlayer
  src={require(`../sounds/${title}.mp3`)}
  controls
ref={(e) => { ReferAudio(e) }}
/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

you can access the player by using `audio`
you can lern more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-audio-player)

Comment: using react-audio-player is optional . use can use useRef() to access the html element

Comment: @NitishKurhadkar if it worked make it as solved so that others with a similar problem can solve thier issue also